# ClassNotFoundException - AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder on EC2 ubuntu instance

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

I want to add mail-sending functionality to my java application on an AWS EC2 ubuntu instance. My mail addresses are already registered in SES dashboard and got verified. The EC2 instance is in eu-west region ireland so AWS SES should be available due to documentation.

I took this sample code from the AWSJavaSDK documentation:

```
AmazonSimpleEmailService client = AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder.standard().build();

SendEmailRequest request = new SendEmailRequest()
    .withSource("sender@example.com")
    .withDestination(
            new Destination().withToAddresses("recipient1@example.com", "recipient2@example.com").withCcAddresses("recipient3@example.com")
                    .withBccAddresses(new ArrayList()))
    .withMessage(
            new Message()
                    .withSubject(new Content().withData("Test email").withCharset("UTF-8"))
                    .withBody(
                            new Body()
                                    .withText(new Content().withData("This is the message body in text format.").withCharset("UTF-8"))))
                                    .withReplyToAddresses(new ArrayList()).withReturnPath("").withSourceArn("").withReturnPathArn("");

SendEmailResult response = client.sendEmail(request);
```

I also included this dependency to my `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ses</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.296</version>
    </dependency>
```

The error message I get is:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/amazonaws/services/simpleemail/AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder
>
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.amazonaws.services.simpleemail.AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder

When I start my application locally there only appears the exception that no region can be found but no problems with finding the class.

Why can the class `AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClientBuilder` not be found on the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a AWS/EC2 related issue. How are you packaging/running your application? Your jar/war is probably missing those classes. It works locally because your IDE adds the library to the classpath...
Your can read up on how to properly package your application here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-create-jar-pkg-maven-no-ide.html